# Strange Grey Button Background on Mobile Only with Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a nav that looks like this:

```
    <nav class="text-center">
      <button class="btn nav-button color-house" type="button"><%= link_to "House", home_house_path, class: "color-house" %></button>
      <button class="btn nav-button color-spouse" type="button"><%= link_to "Spouse", home_spouse_path, class: "color-spouse" %></button>
      <button class="btn nav-button color-kids" type="button"><%= link_to "Kids", home_kids_path, class: "color-kids" %></button>
      <button class="btn nav-button color-neutral" type="button"><%= link_to "Blog", blogs_path %></button>
    </nav>
```

Which works out fine on a computer:
[image]

But for some strange reason has a strange grey background on a mobile device:
[image]

The weird part is if I try the chrome inspector's mobile simulator, it looks totally fine...the image only appears with the unwanted grey on an actual phone.

The link to the heroku site is [here](https://stay-sane-mom.herokuapp.com/) in case you want to see the actual thing.

I feel like this has to be some kind of Bootstrap 4 thing, as I've never experienced this behavior on a site without it.

I've tried `background-color: white !important` on `btn` and `nav-button`, but to no avail. The only custom CSS I currently have is this:

```
$color-house: #84C99A;
$color-spouse: #313E50;
$color-kids: #EFB0A1;
$color-neutral: #B7AD99;
$color-black: #26010C;

.color-house { color: $color-house; }
.color-spouse { color: $color-spouse; }
.color-kids { color: $color-kids; }
.color-neutral { color: $color-neutral; }
.color-neutral-hover:hover { color: $color-black; }

.nav-button a {
  font-family: $font-script;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  border-top: solid thin white;
  border-top: solid thin white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .nav-button a {
    margin: 10px 5px 30px 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this .btn {background: transparent;}

Comment: this also seems to happen in safari and ff, so i doubt it's a mobile error

Comment: @rebecca Argh!  I hadn't even thought it could be a cross-browser thing as well!  Thanks!

Comment: @VarshaDhadge Yes, that fixed it!  If you write it up as an answer I'll happily accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add background transparent property to .btn class

```
.btn {background: transparent;}
```

Comment: Hi, this works. But can you please explain the reason that we have to make it transparent